# SQL "not a valid month"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in sql as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Reserves(
    sid INTEGER,
    bid INTEGER,
    day DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (sid, bid, day),
    FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Sailors,
    FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES Boats
);
```

and I'm trying to insert into it:

```
INSERT INTO Reserves VALUES(22, 101, '01-01-1998');
```

But I get the error: ORA-01843: not a valid month

This is an Oracle db.  I'm not sure what's wrong with my date format.

Comment: As a general rule you should always use a culture inspecific date format (yyyyMMdd) unless you are declaring the date format explcitly. `02-01-2012` could be 2nd January 2012 or 1st February 2012, however `20120102` is **always** 2nd January 2012

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's not entirely clear which you wanted, so you could try:

- For month-day-year format:

  `INSERT INTO Reserves VALUES(22, 101, TO_DATE('01-01-1998','MM-DD-YYYY'));`
- For day-month-year format:

  `INSERT INTO Reserves VALUES(22, 101, TO_DATE('01-01-1998','DD-MM-YYYY'));`

Also, recommended reading: [Oracle functions: TO_DATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `date` keyword to specify an ANSI-standard date string:

```
INSERT INTO Reserves VALUES(22, 101, date '1998-01-01');
```

In this case, the format is YYYY-MM-DD, or January 1, 1998.

Comment: Thanks Bob.  I was hoping there was a way that I wouldn't have to use the TO_DATE function.

Answer (score 8):

As @Jody also mentioned,
You can change the default for your session by executing this code once before `INSERT` :

`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY';`

You may alter the format in any order you like.

**Source:** [dba-oracle.com](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nls_date_format.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Try '1998-01-01'.

I believe the default date format for oracle is yyyy-mm-dd.  You can change the default for your session by using  alter session set nls_date_format='mm-dd-yyyy'

Keep in mind that most clients let you set this to whatever you like permanently

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try in below query format:

`INSERT INTO Reserves VALUES(22, 101, DATE '01-01-1998');`

`DATE` keyword interprets the following string as a date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will solve your issue

```
INSERT INTO Reserves VALUES(22, 101, TO_DATE('01-01-1998','DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Comment: How is this different than the accepted answer?