# Oracle PL/SQL - Not a valid month error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create calendar table using this PL/SQL script from Oracle site: 
[Date Dimension Data Generator](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_D483FJ633JTDU61TWX2N71EC3.html)

Everything works good, but I cannot run statement from section 5:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(UDF_CALENDAR_GENERATOR(CAST('1-JAN-2016' AS DATE), CAST('31-DEC-2016' AS DATE)));
```

I get error:

> 1843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
>
> *Cause:
>   *Action:

I tried to use `to_date` function (based od [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13002605/6898608)):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(UDF_CALENDAR_GENERATOR(TO_DATE('14-Apr-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE('14-May-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')));
```

But it doesn't work. What is wrong with this statement?

Comment: Have you run `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY';` before calling the function,  as suggested in your linked page ?

Comment: Do you have to pass the dates in with the months written out? If not, you can use the numeric month values, e.g. `to_date('14/04/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` to avoid the nls language differences. Failing that, you could use hekko's solution of specifying the language you're passing the date in with.

Comment: No, I don't have to, but when I replace `CAST('1-JAN-2016' AS DATE)` with `to_date('14/04/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` script fails with `not valid month` error. And when I set `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'Polish'` it fails too. So I think the script does not work for other languages than American.

Comment: `'Apr'` assumes English month names. For Polish it would be `'Kwi'`. (As an English speaker from England, I hate it that `'American'` is counted as a language.)

Comment: `to_date('14/04/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` shouldn't fail with the not valid month error. Are you sure you replaced all instances of the named month with the numeric format in your script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must be a date format issue, be sure that your date format is `DD-MON-YYYY` and ,since you're using English, be also sure that your date languate is English:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY';

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'American';
```

Comment: The second statement fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(
    UDF_CALENDAR_GENERATOR(
        TO_DATE('14-Apr-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'), 
        TO_DATE('14-May-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Someone should tell the author that in Oracle, [date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) are written like `date '2016-01-01'`, so the query should be:

```
select *
from   table(udf_calendar_generator(date '2016-01-01', date '2016-12-31'));
```

The `CAST()` expression is effectively `TO_DATE()` with no date format or language specified, requiring an element of luck for it to work in any given environment.

Answer (score 1):

Find default date format:
SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;

in sql developer:
at beginning of query:
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY';

at end of query (to return to default format):
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR';

BUT stored procedure is different.
after the BEGIN:
execute immediate 'alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ''MM/DD/YYYY''';

At end of stored procedure, just before 'END ' :
execute immediate 'alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ''DD-MON-RR''';